# python convert plain text to mathml

Tags: python, latex, mathml

I have a string "x1/4 + y3/8"

I want its mathml value similar to {x}\frac{{{1}}}{{{4}}}%2B{y}\frac{{{3}}}{{{8}}}

I am trying to use following codes:

- latex("x1/4 + y3/8") or latex(sympy.simpify("x1/4 + y3/8")): Response to this is x not defined
- If run latex("1/4 + 3/8") or latex(sympy.simpify("1/4 + 3/8")): Response to this is \frac{{{1/3}}}

I need to pass this to separate server that converts the above to an image.

Plese help

Comment: Since your original question was how to get MathML, and synthesizerpatal answered it (even if you meanwhile found out you need in fact a LaTeX representation), I suggest to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The mathdom module is nice enough to handle this for you:

http://mathdom.sourceforge.net/

```
from mathml.lmathdom import MathDOM # use lxml implementation
doc = MathDOM.fromString("+2^x+4*-5i/6","infix_term")   # parse infix term
```

Comment: I am getting output as '<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><apply><plus/><apply><power/><cn type="integer">2</cn><ci>x</ci></apply><apply><times/><cn type="integer">4</cn><apply><divide/><cn type="complex">0<sep/>-5</cn><cn type="integer">6</cn> </apply></apply></apply></math>'

Need +{2}^{x}+4{*}-\frac{5}{i}{6}

Comment: e.g http://math.gototest.com/cgi-bin/mathtex.cgi?\displaystyle+{2}^{x}+4{*}-\frac{5}{i}{6}

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the problem - mathml is an XML representation of mathmatic equations. If you want the latex representation, there's probably a different converter - or, you could parse the MathML XML and create it. There are also xslt transformations available that you might want to inspect. The Python module is capable of generating HTML+CSS that will produce HTML markup that represents the math problem (which is _better than an image since you can cut and paste parts of it).. I urge you to dig deeper.

Comment: After searching for more I realized that I need to convert to Latex Math Expression. I guess I will have to find a xml to latext math expression convertor.